# gradle spring boot project: How to rename files in war?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am building a web application using Spring Boot.
I would like to change some names of WEB-INF/lib/*.jars in the final.

If I understand the docs correctly, this should work using the "rename" method of the bootWar task (a subclass of the standard war task) which is supplied by the spring-boot-gradle-plugin.

However the "rename" method is never executed at all, i.e. if I add this to my build.gradle:

```
   bootWar {
      rename { name ->
        println "***** " + name
        name
    }
```

then nothing gets printed at all. The "rename" method overloads that take an original pattern and a replacement pattern do not work either.

I tried it with an example project, and it did not work there either:

- use Spring Initializr with "Web" dependency to create a new project
- change the `apply plugin: 'java'` to `apply plugin: 'war'`
- add the `bootWar` configuration from above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `rename` method on the `bootWar.rootSpec` as follows:

```
bootWar {
    rootSpec.rename { name ->
        println "***** " + name
        name
    }
}
```

Then you will have hand to rename the libs you need:

```
> Task :bootWar
***** MANIFEST.MF   
***** spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar 
***** spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar 
***** spring-boot-starter-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
( ...)
```

I don't know the reasons for that, but the `rename` closure from `War` task will be only applied to resources located under your project's `src/main/webapp` directory, not other resources (like dependencies). You can confirm this by creating a dummy resource `src/main/webapp/foo.txt`and execute your test script :

```
$ ./gradlew bootWar

> Task :bootWar
***** foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Out of curiosity: Where can I RTFM to find out about "rootSpec"? I cannot find that property anywhere in the gradle api docs.

Comment: War task inherits from AbstractCopyTask: `rootSpec` property is handled at this level, see here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html . But you will not find much information about usage of this 'rootSpec' there, unfortunately.

Comment: wuldn't it be easier to use archiveName (inside bootWar task)

Comment: @AnanthaSharma `archiveName` controls the name of the produced `war` archive file. the question here is about name of `jar` files contained in the produced `war`